# 4 Sets of Co-Ordinates, Calculate the points of intersection

Tags: intersection-theory

I have 4 sets of co-ordinates that need to be plotted and then I need to find a point of intersection. However, I do not know exactly where the points need to intersect. What I do know is that the co-ordinates would more than likely be pairs. as below:

-493.445323,    705.4917993
-617.9098973,   885.965432

AND

-965.215678 372.421357
-865.215678 572.421357

How do I go about calculating the point of intersection?
I could possible have 3-4 different solutions here. As each line may also be extended parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the point of intersection of the lines passing through those points, using those points, find the gradient of the line and then substitute it into y=mx+c (the equation of a straight line) to find out its equation. Set the two equations equal to each other and solve the equation (it has a unique solution unless the lines are parallel).